# Move files with wildcard?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, move

Ohhhh, I've read a few pages and questions, but I just can't comprehend/fully understand it...

```
jdir0="$@"  # /home/tor/subbackup/teest2/jjj
mv  "$jdir0/subs/*.srt" /home/tor/subbackup/
```

***mv: cannot stat '/home/tor/subbackup/teest2/jjj/*.srt': No such file or directory***

Well, duh, yes, there is one test2.srt in there..

I've seen a few pages with tons of different solutions, and a as I have understood it, this should be translated to(the first move command):

```
mv /home/tor/subbackup/teest2/jjj/subs/test2.srt /home/tor/subbackup/
```

This one works fine in the terminal..

(The first move command), but I can't get it to work in the script.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You should not quote a glob if you want it to be expanded.  Change `"$jdir0/subs/*.srt"` to `"$jdir0"/subs/*.srt`. Also, please try to make a minimal example, apparently the first half of the script  has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: understood, thx for the tip..

Comment: I am confused. Are you doing the sarcasm right. You say "Well, duh, yes," then make a complete 180° turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jdir0="$@"
```

`"$@"` expands to *all* positional parameters / arguments to the script. When you assign it to a single variable, Bash concatenates them joined with spaces. You probably want just `$1` here.

```
mv "$jdir0/subs/*.srt"
```

The variable expansion should indeed be quoted, since it prevents word splitting, and globbing if the variable contains something that looks like a glob. But here, you probably want the hard-coded glob to work, so it should *not* be quoted.

So leave the asterisk outside quotes, with e.g.

```
mv "$jdir0"/subs/*.srt
```

or e.g.

```
mv "$jdir0/subs/"*.srt
```

Both work the same, use which ever variant looks nicer to you.

Comment: .. that's the big difference from windows (pre win10) I was for windows, and there it was only one way to solve issues, with Linux there's so many solutions that I'm getting lightheaded.. thx for the info @ilkkachu