# Moving files with " and * caused error

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, mv, move

I'm having trouble with moving files in a bash script.
I've been trying different solutions that I've found here, on the same problem, but can't find anything that works..

my last attempt was adding `shopt -s dotglob nullglob` but that didn't solve anything..

In this test,

```
jdir0="/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(6th.copy)..kansas.(1999)"


mv -v "$jdir0/*" "$jdir0/subs/" &>> $debuglog
```

.. and I get:

```
mv: cannot stat '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(6th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/*': No such file or directory
```

but, yes, there are!

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   4096 Aug 22 07:06  ../
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 21 17:19 'kallee.(222)..nnn.srt'*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 159363 Aug 21 17:26 'movie.test(2929).ismim.mp4'*
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf      0 Aug 22 07:06  subs/
```

(the reason the names are really strange is that I before this function is testing to remove invalid chars)

update: Apparently I got intermittent errors, and I've finally after days traced it back to server issue (where the files where stored).
Apparently these errors occurred if the server wasn't finished with the save/name change, and the script asked it to do something new.
For example renaming file A to B, and then asking it to rename B to C BEFORE the server had executed the first request, which resulted in that the server said: B don't exist, which of course caused an error code.

Comment: yes, the $ there isn't there in the script, it was only a way to "explain", but I'll update the question..

Comment: Didn't you ask this before? [Move files with wildcard?
](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604983/170373)

Comment: @ilkkachu omg, I had asked this.. sorry forgot it (see my profile).. I was so up in it because sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't work, so I thought I made mistakes, when it actually was a strange server issue (see the updated question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` is a glob operator of the shell. It needs to be left unquoted to be recognised as such. When quoted, `/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(6th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/*` is passed literally to `mv` and `mv` tries to move that file called `*`, and there's no such file.

So you need:

```
mv -v -- "$jdir0"/* "$jdir0/subs/" >> "$debuglog" 2>&1
```

For the shell to expand `"$jdir0"/*` into the list of matching files before calling `mv`.

You do *not* want `nullglob` here as that would mean that in the absence of files matching that `"$jdir0"/*` pattern, `mv` would be invoked with just `-v`, `--` and `media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(6th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/subs/` causing a confusing syntax error by `mv`.

`failglob` to abort command when the globs don't match may be a better option in that case, though note that `bash` aborts in inconsistent ways in that case depending on the context the command is invoked in, which makes that option tricky to use in scripts.

`dotglob` is to allow globs to match hidden files.

Now, note that globs match files regardless of their type¹, so that `*` above will also match `subs`. If `subs` is a symlink to a directory, `mv` will happily move that `subs` symlink into that directory, causing all subsequent moves to fail as the `subs` target directory is now gone. If `subs` is a plain subdirectory, `mv` will likely complain that it can't move a directory into itself.

So you may want to write it instead:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -v -- "$jdir0"/!(subs) "$jdir0/subs/" >> "$debuglog" 2>&1
```

Where `!(pattern)` is the ksh extended glob operator that matches on any filename that does *not* match `pattern`, so here moving any file but `subs`.

Also note that in the `bash` shell, parameter expansions also need to be quoted when in targets of redirections even in non-interactive shell instances (except when bash is in POSIX mode).

---

<sup>¹ unless you use zsh instead of bash and its glob qualifiers such as `*(.)` to move only *regular* files</sup>

Comment: @JoBe, same, but standard `sh` syntax and more explicit (`&>> file` is a bash-specific operator to redirect both fds 1 and 2 in append mode to `file`, similar to `csh`/`zsh`'s `>>&`).

Comment: getting error with your code: `mv: cannot move '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(8th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/kallee.(222)..nnn.srt' to '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(8th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/subs/kallee.(222)..nnn.srt': Not a directory
mv: cannot move '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(8th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/movie.test(2929).ismim.mp4' to '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(8th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/subs/movie.test(2929).ismim.mp4': Not a directory
`

Comment: @JoBe, that would be the error you get when `subs` is not a directory. I'd guess you have made several attempts, one of which has moved `subs` elsewhere and one of which renamed a file to `subs`. Check the contents of your directory again.

Comment: nope, the subs directory is there, it creates it (and checks if it exists) just before attempting to move the files...

Comment: @JoBe Try and add a `set -o xtrace` at the beginning of your script to see what is being executed.

Comment: if I'm doing your first tip, by placing the * outside it works (but complain about it can't move subs into itself).   is there anyway to get the output from xtrace to a file?

Comment: @JoBe: `exec 7>> ~/xtrace.log; BASH_XTRACEFD=7; set -o xtrace`

Comment: `
+ mv -v -- '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(5th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/kallee.(222)..nnn.srt' '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(5th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/movie.test(2929).ismim.mp4' '/media/sf_Mediaserver3/test22/abbamax.(5th.copy)..kansas.(1999)/subs/'
+ jok=1`

Comment: @JoBe, that looks like a correct command. If that fails, you could try and move one file by hand and see what happens. It sounds like there's something fishy with the file system at `/media/sf_Mediaserver3`

Comment: but your first solution, put the * outside the "     "$jdir0/"* works fine, except it complains about that it can't move the subs directory into it self, but that's a logical and legit complain...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112108/discussion-between-jobe-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: :55320273 @Stéphane I have found something REALLY strange, I couldn't understand why it worked sometimes and why I didn't sometimes, then I realized that sometimes it too a few milliseconds longer, and those times it worked. I added a 2 second pause before moving the files, and now it works everytime (at least 20 times in a row).. I'm strongly suspecting that something else is "locking"the file, (the files are on another encrypted server), and the script was to fast.. does this sound plausible? don't have any other suggestions to the intermittent working/not working..